# /app/.jdk/bin/java: cannot execute binary file using node-pty on Heroku

Tags: java, node.js, heroku, node-pty

I am trying to create a node-pty process. When developing locally, this works fine and there is no problem. However, when this runs on Heroku, it gives the error: `/app/.jdk/bin/java: cannot execute binary file`

I tried running it with just `["java"]`, and that gives the same error. So, its unable to start the java binary.

However, when I manually type the command, it works just fine.

```
  const shell = os.platform() === 'win32' ? 'powershell.exe' : 'bash';

  const ptyProcess = pty.spawn(shell, ["java", "-jar", "Klox.jar"], {
    name: 'xterm-color',
    cols: 80,
    rows: 30,
    cwd: process.env.HOME,
    env: process.env
  });
```

Any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem,

Instead of spawning the shell with powershell or bash, spawn the shell directly with the executable that you're trying to run. So, `java` in my case.

Effectively, what I did:

```
  const ptyProcess = pty.spawn("java", ["-jar", "Klox.jar"], {
    name: 'xterm-color',
    cols: 80,
    rows: 30,
    cwd: process.env.HOME,
    env: process.env
  });
```

So, "java" instead of old shell variable.

One another thing to keep in mind, on windows add `.exe` extension to the end, otherwise it will say file not found. For eg: `java.exe` on windows and `java` on linux.